# Pandas installation on python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64

Tags: python, pandas, pip, python-2.6

Currently our Linux production server is having python-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 , So can we install Pandas on this version of python ?  (some websites says that 2.6 is no more support for this but still wanted to confirm)

Thanks for you response. Quick response would be helpful.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

[Version 0.17.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandas/0.17.1) seems to be the last one that supported Python 2.6. Install with pip

```
pip install pandas==0.17.1
```

or from [sources](https://pypi.python.org/packages/a9/8e/034d108c2b2834ad4cc5bf7fb2b4d96bacf135034a2e2d946f7b4661d461/pandas-0.17.1.tar.gz#md5=1e18b9a5496ec92752b3cb6674bbe987).

Comment: where can i find the step by step installation guide as i am newbie to this.

Comment: Let's me guess… in the [pandas' docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/install.html)? You haven't even tried. :-(